# Opengraph Image meta Tags priority order

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

When I set up meta tags for content I share through Facebook, I add two different urls in the tag og:image and og:image:url . When I share the content on Facebook, always the image in og:image is embedded in the share link.

What I need to know is, How does facebook choose which image to embed in the sharing post, and which meta tags take priority.

Comment: Does it matter? Why are you specifying two different images?

Comment: @WizKid this is automatically done by the CMS through which I share the content.

Comment: Then change the CMS to only add one

Answer (score 1):

Drupal CMS also use several fields for the Metatags Open Graph image sharing management.

It appears that there are no priority. Not mentionned on the documentation https://ogp.me/

Some social networks and tools use in priority og:image (Facebook), other og:image:url and og:image:secure_url (LinkedIn).

With Drupal I only keep one field to be used, I think that you'll be able to override or configure it.